# True or false: The negation of $∃x : P(x)$ is $∃x, \neg P(x)$

Tags: predicate-logic

I am trying to understand the negation of propositional logic with regards to universal and existential quantifiers.  I want to know if the negation of $∃x, P(x)$ is $∃x, \neg P(x)$ is true or false.  I believe that this is true.  I know that the negation of a universal quantifier is usually an existential quantifier, and I believe the negation of an existential quantifier is still an existential quantifier.  Can anybody let me know if I am correct?

Comment: False. The negation is $\forall x, \lnot P(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False: $\neg \left(\exists x : P(x) \right) \equiv \forall x, \, \neg P(x)$.

Think of this logically. The statement $\exists x : P(x)$ means that there exists (one or more) $x$ so that $P(x)$ is true. Your incorrect negation says that there exists one $x$ so that $P(x)$ is false.

For example, consider the statement: there exists a black horse.

The incorrect negation would be: there exists a horse that is not black.

The correct negation would be: for each horse, that horse is not black.

Comment: This makes sense.  Thank you for clarifying.  Would it be right to assume then that the negation of a universal quantifier is an existential quantifier, and the negation of an existential quantifier is a universal quantifier?

Comment: Yes. Precisely.

Answer (score 3):

The negation of “there is some $x$ such that $P(x)$” is “not $P(x)$ for any $x$.”

In other words, “for all $x$, not $P(x)$.”

Formally: $\forall x,\neg P(x)$.

---

Intuitively, the negation of an existential quantifier boils down to the use of a universal quantifier after all, but in quite a sneaky way: the non-existence of something is equivalent to *all* things *not* being that something.

For example, let $U(x)$ be the statement that “$x$ is a unicorn.” Then, the statement $\neg[\exists x:U(x)]$ “unicorns don't exist” is equivalent to the statement that “$\textit{every}\text{thing}$ that does exist is *not* a unicorn,” that is, $[\forall x:\neg U(x)]$. The latter worded statement is in blatant defiance of English semantics (though grammatically correct), but it nevertheless shows where the universal quantifier is hidden in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. The negation of an existential quantifier is a universal quantifier. To see this, take an example:

If I claimed that there exists a mad man in town X, then to prove me wrong, you will have to verify that every person in town X is not mad. Not that there exists a person in town X who is not mad, because basically that says nothing about whether or not my statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the answer to your question is **no**, but it may help to see an example of how to negate statements appropriately. The basic idea is to "push the negation through," changing all $\exists$ signs to $\forall$ and vice-versa and then negate the proposition $P$.

I actually asked a generalized question about [negating quantifiers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095530/negation-of-quantifiers) a good while back. You can see the basic idea as follows: suppose we have 
$$
(\exists x\in\mathbb{R})(\forall y\in\mathbb{R})(y>x).\tag{1}
$$
What would be the negation of this? Using the idea of "pushing the negation through":
$$
(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(\exists y\in\mathbb{R})(y\leq x).\tag{2}
$$
Can you see how $(2)$ is the negation of $(1)$? It may help further to consider a more [linguistic problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129668/how-to-express-the-statement-not-all-rainy-days-are-cold-using-predicate-logic) that was asked a while back.

Answer (score 1):

When you think about existence and universal, it helps to translate from colloquial English to math-y English to symbols.

### *The negation of exists is universal.*

**English**: There is an apple in the basket.

**Math-y English**: there exists some apple (in the basket is true).

**Symbols** $\exists x P(x)$

When you negate you get the following:

**English**: There are no apples in the basket.

**Mathy-y English**: for all apples (in the basket is false)

**Symbols**: $\forall x ~P(x)$

---

### *The negation of universal is existence.*

**English**: All apples are in the basket.

**Math-y English**: for all apples (in the basket is true)

**Symbols**: $\forall x P(x)$

When you negate you get the following:

**English**: There is an apple not in the basket.

**Math-y English**: there exists some apple (in the basket is false)

**Symbols**: $\exists x ~P(x)$

---

Think about this a little while, it will make sense.